# flutter android SQlite 'code 1 SQLITE_ERROR, no column named'

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite, dart

Currently using SQlite, practicing how to save text from textfield. I can do it with only 1 textfield, but when make it even as low as 1 more textfield, it fails me.

> Exception has occurred. SqfliteDatabaseException (DatabaseException(table claims has no column named number (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO claims (id, name, number) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)) sql 'INSERT INTO claims (id, name, number) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)' args [tt, 605])

```html
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors

import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

// https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noi6aYsP7Go
// this is where im getting all these from

main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(SqliteApp());
}

class SqliteApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const SqliteApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SqliteAppState createState() => _SqliteAppState();
}

class _SqliteAppState extends State<SqliteApp> {
  int? selectedId;
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  final textController2 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('TEST TEST')),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextField(
                    controller: textController,
                  ),
                  TextField(
                    controller: textController2,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 500,
                    child: FutureBuilder<List<Claim>>(
                      future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getClaim(),
                      builder: (BuildContext context,
                          AsyncSnapshot<List<Claim>> snapshot) {
                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                          return Center(
                            child: Text('Loading...'),
                          );
                        }
                        return snapshot.data!.isEmpty
                            ? Center(
                                child: Text('No Claims in List.'),
                              )
                            : ListView(
                                children: snapshot.data!.map((claim) {
                                  return Center(
                                    child: Card(
                                      color: selectedId == claim.id
                                          ? Colors.grey
                                          : Colors.white,
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title: Text(claim.name),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            if (selectedId == null) {
                                              textController.text = claim.name;
                                              textController2.text =
                                                  claim.number;
                                              selectedId = claim.id;
                                            } else {
                                              textController.text = '';
                                              textController2.text = '';
                                              selectedId = null;
                                            }
                                          });
                                        },
                                        onLongPress: () {
                                          setState(() {
                                            DatabaseHelper.instance
                                                .remove(claim.id!);
                                          });
                                        },
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }).toList(),
                              );
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.save),
          onPressed: () async {
            if (textController.text.isEmpty) {
              null;
            } else {
              selectedId != null
                  ? await DatabaseHelper.instance.update(
                      Claim(
                          id: selectedId,
                          name: textController.text,
                          number: textController2.text),
                    )
                  : await DatabaseHelper.instance.add(
                      Claim(
                          name: textController.text,
                          number: textController2.text),
                    );
              setState(() {
                textController.clear();
                textController2.clear();
              });
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Claim {
  final int? id;
  final String name;
  final String number;

  Claim({this.id, required this.name, required this.number});

  factory Claim.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      new Claim(id: json['id'], name: json['name'], number: json['number']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'number': number,
    };
  }
}

class DatabaseHelper {
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database?
      _database; // if the variable doesnt exist,,,,,,,, this (under) will initalise the database, and use set variable
  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, 'claims.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 2,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE claims(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT
        number TEXT
      )
    ''');
  }

  Future<List<Claim>> getClaim() async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var claims = await db.query('claims', orderBy: 'id');
    List<Claim> claimList =
        claims.isNotEmpty ? claims.map((c) => Claim.fromMap(c)).toList() : [];
    return claimList;
  }

  Future<int> add(Claim claim) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert('claims', claim.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> remove(int id) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete('claims', where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  Future<int> update(Claim claim) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.update('claims', claim.toMap(),
        where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [claim.id]);
  }
}
```

With this code, I keep getting the code 1 SQLITE_ERROR, i tried tweaking it over and over again but alas, can't find the solution. Still quite an amateur in flutter so I don't have much experience

Comment: Please post the full error too.

Comment: ah will do! forgive me, still quite new to this

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed a comma when creating the Claim table

```
Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE claims(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT,
        number TEXT
      )
    ''');
  }
```

I would like to propose a better way for readability

```
db.execute(
  "CREATE TABLE claims("
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
    "name TEXT, "
    "number TEXT)"
);
```

Comment: dude i thought you got it istg if that was the problem id punch myself, but alas i tried it but still had the same error coming out :/ but thank you tho! ill update that

Comment: I updated my answer, how about my proposed way, maybe you also missing the space after comma

Comment: just tried it but still getting the same error. :/// been on this for 2 days and its just one small thing jesus.

Answer (score 0):

The **name** of the database table is not comma (,) after the **TEXT** of the column,
**name TEXT,**

Change the **version : 1**, **uninstall the app from your physical device** and **reinstall**.

Hopefully the problem will be solved.

```
Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE claims(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name TEXT, //You didn't give a comma here
            number TEXT
          )
        ''');
      }
```

**Otherwise follow my code**

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqlite;

class SQLHelper {
  static Future<sqlite.Database> db() async {
    return sqlite.openDatabase("info.db", version: 1,
        onCreate: (sqlite.Database database, int version) {
      database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE note (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, title TEXT, description TEXT)");
      database.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE userdata (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, name TEXT, phone TEXT, email TEXT, password TEXT)");
    });
  }

  static Future<int> insertData(String title, String description) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    var values = {"title": title, "description": description};
    return db.insert("note", values);
  }

  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getAllData() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.query("note", orderBy: "id");
  }

  static Future<int> updateData(
      int id, String title, String description) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    var values = {"title": title, "description": description};
    return db.update("note", values, where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }

  static Future<int> deleteData(int id) async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db();
    return db.delete("note", where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [id]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand what you mean, but im assuming it has to do with the comma (.) after 'name TEXT'. but i tried reinstalling it and check for updated version but still doesnt work

Comment: Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
        await db.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE claims(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
            name TEXT,    // You didn't give a comma here
            number TEXT
          )
        ''');
      }

contact me https://www.facebook.com/nezam.cst/

Comment: ohh understood, if you saw the answer before this, they proposed this already, and ive tried it. but it still does not work

Comment: You see, I have given some more code...